# Transform Feedback with offset

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a transform feedback setup, which is working correctly. It has an input of say 1000 Vertices and feedbacks the same number of vertices.

http://prideout.net/blog/?p=67 is the reference for our implementation.
Now as part of optimisation i need to limit the feedback vertex count with an offset. Means i should be able to render the last 500 vertices and feedback it to location 500 - 1000 in the feedback buffer. We thought about having multiple VBO setup but we think its could be a performance hit, since we need to keep changing the bind buffer.
Please sugggest best way to accomplish this .

Comment: They're only called "VBOs" when you use them as sources for vertex data. They're just buffer objects when you're using them for arbitrary things like transform feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having multiple buffer object setups. Performance hit or no, that's how it's done.